# Change name of json property key's in javascript rekursive to store as json in postgreSQL

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql

I try to store a JSON object into a postgreSQL tabel. The JSON Objects I've got have a structure like:

```
{
  "$base": "Object",
  "displayName": "Test_DC_CAL_78901234567890123456789012345678901234567890äöüßÄÖÜ",
  "object-name": {
    "$base": "String",
    "value": "Test_DC_CAL_78901234567890123456789012345678901234567890äöüßÄÖÜ"
  },
  "object-identifier": {
    "$base": "ObjectIdentifier",
    "value": "calendar,701001"
  },
  "object-type": {
    "$base": "Enumerated",
    "value": "calendar"
  },
  "description": {
    "$base": "String",
    "value": "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890äöüß"
  },
  "date-list": {
    "1": {
      "$base": "Choice",
      "date": {
        "$base": "Choice",
        "date": {
          "$base": "DatePattern",
          "value": "*-12-25-*"
        }
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "$base": "Choice",
      "date": {
        "$base": "Choice",
        "date": {
          "$base": "DatePattern",
          "value": "*-12-26-*"
        }
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "$base": "Choice",
      "weekNDay": {
        "$base": "Sequence",
        "month": {
          "$base": "Enumerated",
          "value": "any"
        },
        "weekOfMonth": {
          "$base": "Enumerated",
          "value": "any"
        },
        "dayOfWeek": {
          "$base": "Enumerated",
          "value": "sunday"
        }
      }
    },
    "4": {
      "$base": "Choice",
      "date": {
        "$base": "Choice",
        "date": {
          "$base": "Date",
          "value": "2020-10-15"
        }
      }
    },
    "5": {
      "$base": "Choice",
      "dateRange": {
        "$base": "Sequence",
        "startDate": {
          "$base": "Date",
          "value": "2020-10-16"
        },
        "endDate": {
          "$base": "Date",
          "value": "2020-10-17"
        }
      }
    },
    "$base": "List"
  },
  "present-value": {
    "$base": "Boolean",
    "value": "1"
  }
}
```

My postgres connector doesn't accept the $base properties. I can delete it, but only property by property. But later I need it again, so I'm looking for a way to rename it in all levels of properties.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` can be called with the [`reviver` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) to make simple modifications to an object tree just after it is parsed from JSON. To rename all `$base` keys to `_base`:

```js
const parsed = JSON.parse(json, function (key, value) {
  if (key === "$base") {
    // Rename key
    this._base = value;
    // Drop old key
    return undefined;
  }
  return value;
});
```